# Kentico: Can i get Page Title via nodeID?

Tags: macros, title, kentico

I would like to display a list of a couple of my pages in a list.

Is there a macro or something else to get the page title of another site then the actual one?
All i need is a little smart function that can give me the name of a page.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you need title of another site or page? It's not clear from your question.

Comment: @rocky i need the title of a page. exact the same way as i do it for the current page with:
<%= CMS.CMSHelper.CMSContext.CurrentResolver.ResolveMacros("{%CurrentDocument.DocumentName#%}")%>
but how can i do this with another page than the active one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the `nodeID` of the page you want the title of, you can use the `TreeHelper` static functions.

```
TreeNode yourNode = TreeHelper.SelectSingleNode(nodeID);
```

then easily enough access the name from there.

```
yourNode.DocumentName;
```

Note the difference between a TreeNode and a Document is that there are possibly multiple Document's for one TreeNode, where each is a different language/culture.